# How to make a sprite fill the image?

Tags: unity, sprites, unity-ui

I created a custom UI Button:

[image]

However, when I use the sprite as the image for a button it doesn't fill out the whole "Collision" area:

[image]

This is an example of how I want it to fill the "Collision" area:

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like you are setting the image up as a 9 slice with 8 of the areas as transparent.

Comment: @Zibelas That seems like the issue to me also. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it appears you are setting up your button as a 9-slice, a technique that resizes the nine areas differently to keep borders sharp or corners round. But in your case you eight out the nine areas are transparent.

Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html

What you want is slicing the normal image as close as possible to the button. After that your button should fill out always the full area.

Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

Depending on how much you want to stretch your button, you might take a closer look on how to get the 9 slice correctly set up.

Comment: I guess the issue was the sprite mode was single and thus the slice button was greyed out. Changing the mode to multiple then slicing worked.